# Formatting multiple lists into a table

Tags: python, list, formatting

I need to format four separate lists (not nested) that look like this:

```
header          =   ["Product:"  ,"Price:"    ,"Quantity:"]

productList     =   ["apple"    ,"banana"     ,"cake"]
productPrice    =   [3.50       ,6.82         ,23.00]
productQty      =   [134        ,52           ,5]
```

into a table that looks like this:

```
Product:        Price:          Quantity
Apple           $3.50           134
Banana          $6.82           52
Cake            $23.00          5
```

I want this table to update with the original source lists. I know I will need to execute this with some sort of loop. So for example if I was to update the lists:

```
header          =   ["Product:"  ,"Price:"    ,"Quantity:"]

productList     =   ["apple"    ,"banana"     ,"cake"     ,"newItem1"]
productPrice    =   [3.50       ,6.82         ,23.00      ,00.00]
productQty      =   [134        ,52           ,5          ,100]
```

the table would now look like:

```
Product:        Price:          Quantity
Apple           $3.50           134
Banana          $6.82           52
Cake            $23.00          5
newItem1        $00.00          100
```

Any ideas? Any help, pointers, or tips would be useful.

Comment: [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72890904/how-to-align-strings-in-columns) for DIY style

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd

header = ["Product:", "Price:", "Quantity:"]
productList = ["apple", "banana", "cake", "newItem1"]
productPrice = [3.50, 6.82, 23.00, 00.00]
productQty = [134, 52, 5, 100]

df = pd.DataFrame({header[0]: productList, header[1]: [f'${p:.2f}' for p in productPrice], header[2]: productQty})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Product:  Price:  Quantity:
0     apple   $3.50        134
1    banana   $6.82         52
2      cake  $23.00          5
3  newItem1   $0.00        100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    # convert below table into a format shown
header          =   ["Product:"  ,"Price:"    ,"Quantity:"]
productList     =   ["apple"    ,"banana"     ,"cake"]
productPrice    =   [3.50       ,6.82         ,23.00]
productQty      =   [134        ,52           ,5]


# make table from header, productList, productPrice, productQty
# convert table into a format shown below
'''
Product:        Price:          Quantity
Apple           $3.50           134
Banana          $6.82           52
Cake            $23.00          5
newItem1        $00.00          100
'''
# make table from header, productList, productPrice, productQty
table=[]
table.append(header)
for i in range(len(productList)):
    table.append([productList[i],productPrice[i],productQty[i]])

#use dataframes, make productlist as index, headers as columns
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(table[1:],columns=table[0])
print(df)
```